# Dns configuration in windows changes unintentionally to manual mode

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp-server

We have a Domain controller (windows server 2012) in our LAN, there is also a DHCP server for clients to get them IP automatically.

[image]

all clients give right ip and dns configurations and work as well but these days we encounter a problem: some clients' DHCP configuration change to **use the following IP server ** unintentionally. and get some unknown DNS servers (172.18.x.x ,  8.8.8.8)

**tips:**

- There are no any modem or dhcp server else.
- The users that login in clients don't have enough permission to change the configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable registry auditing, and enable auditing for write/set permissions on the following key:

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces

[image: Audit]

[image: Registry]

Comment: Where it should be applied? in Domain controller or Clients ?

Comment: The system where the change is occurring.

Comment: Great, today I found the software that causes this problem. but I don't know how to restirct the software to prevent  Dns configuration changes.